# When does the garbage collector in c# exit

Tags: c#

Does the garbage collector shutdown after the entire Main method has finished executing or does it still run in the background to clean up all the objects the Main method has left over in the memory.

Comment: Finalizers still need to be run after main has exited, so it's somewhere shortly after all user code has finished execution that the GC/framework terminates. It would be interesting to have a technical, correct answer to this.

Comment: The application usually terminates when the Main method (and as such the program’s entry point) finishes. At this point, the GC may run for a bit, but eventually, the operating system will clear up all allocated memory.

Comment: garbage collector is running in a *separate thread*, so it can well be proceeding even if `Main` is returned

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The garbage collector will run in the background at program exit to run pending finalizers, but if the finalizers take too long, it will give up and exit prematurely.

You can demonstrate this with the following program:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class Test
    {
        ~Test()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            Trace.WriteLine("In Test finalizer");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var t = new Test[20];

            for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
                t[i] = new Test();

            //t = null;
            //GC.Collect();
            //GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }
    }
}
```

Run that program under the debugger and you will see that only some of the 20 finalizers are actually run before the GC gives up.

However, you can ensure that all pending finalizers are completely run at the end of the program by calling

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

If you uncomment the three commented-out lines at the end of `Main()` in the sample code above and run the program under the debugger again, you'll see that all 20 calls to the `Test` finalizer will be made.

Answer (score 0):

Once a process terminates, all the resources that belonged to it are freed. This is performed by the operating system. GC is for managed resource.

I'm guessing main is the entrypoint method in this case e.g in a console app.

Comment: For C# executables, main is almost always the entry point, even when you have forms.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector (GC) is started with your app and will exit with it.
During your app lifetime it runs in background to free managed resources.

The GC is spawned by the .net framework itself.

Comment: what about garbage collector with respect to Main method